# Overlaying two images with cv2 results as a noise

Tags: python, opencv, blending

I'm trying to blend 3 images.

1. First i overlay [photo.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNOht.png) over [base.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg7ni.jpg) with some positioning. And it works.

[base_photo.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0P2X.png)

2. Second i'm trying to overlay `effect.png`

[effect.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSJuW.png)

over resulting image from previous step.

The result looks like this

[result.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RudX9.png)

I'm using opencv blending described [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/dc4/tutorial_adding_images.html). I've tried to use `cv2.addWeighted` but the result was the same

```py
# blending function
def img_overlay(background, overlay, x_offset, y_offset):
    y1, y2 = y_offset, y_offset + overlay.shape[0]
    x1, x2 = x_offset, x_offset + overlay.shape[1]

    alpha_s = overlay[:, :, 3] / 255.0
    alpha_l = 1.0 - alpha_s

    for c in range(0, 3):
        background[y1:y2, x1:x2, c] = (alpha_s * overlay[:, :, c] +
                                   alpha_l * background[y1:y2, x1:x2, c])

    return background

# First step
background = cv2.imread('base.png')
overlay = cv2.imread('photo.png', -1)
x_offset = 386
y_offset = 70
base_photo = img_overlay(background, overlay, x_offset, y_offset)

# Second step
overlay = cv2.imread('effect.png', -1)
final_photo = img_overlay(base_photo, overlay, 0, 0)

cv2.imwrite(result, final_photo)
```

How i can fix `img_overlay` function so it will overlay `effect.png` correctly?

Comment: The blending math is causing values slightly outside the normal range. After doing your blending clip the background result to the range 0 to 255. See cv2.clip(0,255)

Comment: You dont even have to be blending. Take a black base picture with the required dimensions, copy the smaller picture to the place of the offset (by creating roi with rectangle) and then copying in the effect with mask (mask will have the inside of the effect set to 0 and outside the effect to 255).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your 'effect' image is in the a different scale.  Correct this by dividing by 255.

Yours 'Second Step' should look like this:

```
# Second step
overlay = cv2.imread('effect.png', -1)
overlay = overlay / 255.0
final_photo = img_overlay(base_photo, overlay, 0, 0)
```

Which works for me.

Comment: @EricUsmanov did this answer solve your problem? If so could you please accept it.  The other two commenters also made valuable contributions which may also help you, but didn't actually answer your initial question.  If you like I can work their comments into a fuller answer.